# RxJS combineLatest from same source

Tags: rxjs

```
const s$ = new Rx.Observable.interval(100).take(4);

const s1$ = s$.map(v => 's1:' + v);
const s2$ = s$.map(v => 's2:' + v);

Rx.Observable.combineLatest(s1$, s2$)
  .subscribe((value) => {
    console.log(value);
  })
```

I want get output like this:

```
s1: 1, s2: 1
s1: 2, s2: 2
s1: 3, s2: 3
```

but real output:

"s1:0,s2:0"

"s1:1,s2:0"

"s1:1,s2:1"

"s1:2,s2:1"

"s1:2,s2:2"

"s1:3,s2:2"

"s1:3,s2:3"

How can i do it ?

Comment: Probably `zip` is the operator you should use rather than `combine latest`. Then the fat that you start from 0 and not from 1 is in the nature of how `interval` works. If you want to start from 1, then either `skip` the first emission or `map` adding 1.

Comment: Thank you dude ! you made my day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the zip operator instead:

```
Rx.Observable.zip(s1$, s2$)
  .subscribe((value) => {
  console.log(value);
})
```